# How to compare multiple string lengths between columns with an R data.table?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data.table

I have the following R data.table `dt`, which is composed of several numeric columns with two columns of character strings.

```
dt = data.table(
      numericvals = rep(25, 8),
      numeric = rep(42, 8),
      first = c("beneficiary, duke", "compose", "herd primary", "stall", "deep", "regular summary classify", "timber", "property"),
      second = rep(c("abcde"), 8)
  )

print(dt)
   numericvals numeric                   first second
1:          25      42        beneficiary, duke abcde
2:          25      42                  compose abcde
3:          25      42             herd primary abcde
4:          25      42                    stall abcde
5:          25      42                     deep abcde
6:          25      42 regular summary classify abcde
7:          25      42                   timber abcde
8:          25      42                 property abcde
```

The column `first` contains one or more strings. If there are more that one, these are separated by either a space or comma.

My goal is to create a column recording the length of strings in `first` which are longer or shorter in length (via `nchar()`) than the strings in `second`. If these are the same size, this case should be ignored.

If the columns were composed of only one string per row, this analysis would be easy for me. I would create a new column called `longer` and keep track of the string length in `first` if it is longer, i.e.

```
dt[, longer:=ifelse(nchar(first) > nchar(second), nchar(first), 0)]
```

and similar for shorter:

```
dt[, shorter:=ifelse(nchar(first) < nchar(second), nchar(first), 0)]
```

I don't know how to deal with multiple strings in `first`, especially if there are 3.

Here is how the analysis should look like:

```
   numericvals numeric                   first second  longer  shorter
1:          25      42        beneficiary, duke abcde  11       4
2:          25      42                  compose abcde  7        0
3:          25      42             herd primary abcde  7        4
4:          25      42                    stall abcde  0        0
5:          25      42                     deep abcde  0        4
6:          25      42 regular summary classify abcde  7, 7, 8  0
7:          25      42                   timber abcde  6        0
8:          25      42                 property abcde  8        0
```

For the case whether there are several longer/shorter, adding commas to the data.table could be cumbersome. This format would be easier to work with, so the end result I want is as follows:

```
   numericvals numeric                   first second  longer  shorter
1:          25      42        beneficiary, duke abcde  11      4
2:          25      42                  compose abcde  7       0
3:          25      42             herd primary abcde  7       4
4:          25      42                    stall abcde  0       0
5:          25      42                     deep abcde  0       4
6:          25      42 regular summary classify abcde  7       0
6:          25      42 regular summary classify abcde  7       0
6:          25      42 regular summary classify abcde  8       0
7:          25      42                   timber abcde  6       0
8:          25      42                 property abcde  8       0
```

How does one compare multiple strings in a data.table, creating new rows for multiple entries?

(I'm using R data.table, but I'm happy to use data.frame as well.)

EDIT: Based on comments below, I realize the second table is wrong. Or at least, values should only be counted once.

Comment: what if there is a `deep regular summary classify`? do you want 1 to be repeated in the `shorter` column for all 3 rows?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Good point. No, it should be counted only once. I think the second table is wrong---users would parse the first table to get all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base functions but wrap inside data.table

For the first output in OP:

```
dt[, do.call(rbind, mapply(function(x, snd) {
        lens <- nchar(x[x!=""])
        longer <- lens[lens > snd]
        if (length(longer) == 0L) longer <- 0L
        shorter <- lens[lens < snd]
        if (length(shorter) == 0L) shorter <- 0L

        list(list(longer), list(shorter))            
    }, strsplit(first, ",| "), nchar(second), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)), by=names(dt)]
```

For the 2nd output in OP,

```
dt[, do.call(rbind, mapply(function(x, snd) {
    lens <- nchar(x[x!=""])
    longer <- lens[lens > snd]
    if (length(longer) == 0L) longer <- 0L
    shorter <- lens[lens < snd]
    if (length(shorter) == 0L) shorter <- 0L

    #pad to equal length
    if (length(longer) > length(shorter)) {
        shorter <- c(shorter, rep(0L, length(longer) - length(shorter)))
    } 
    if (length(longer) < length(shorter)) {
        longer <- c(longer, rep(0L, length(shorter) - length(longer)))
    }

    #second kind of output
    data.frame(longer, shorter)
}, strsplit(first, ",| "), nchar(second), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)), by=names(dt)]
```

Explanation:
First split each string into words using `strsplit(first, ",| ")`, then apply the OP requirements in checking for word length greater than or smaller than word length of the reference column. Then, row bind results into a data.frame and return the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For the first operation, I get the following error: " Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , do.call(rbind, mapply(function(x, snd) { :                                                                                                                
   column or expression 2 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type list. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]"

Comment: I tried `setkey()` for both columns. Here's the error with `first`: "setkey(dt, first)                                                                                                                                                                           
 Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) :                                                                                                                           
   Column 'first' is type 'list' which is not supported as a key column type, currently."

Comment: Did you run your code to create dt in your OP? Or are you using your actual dataset? Your actual dataset might contain list in a column. You can use by=seq_len(dt[,.N]) for your actual dataset

Comment: Yes, for my data set, apparently I needed `by=seq_len(dt[,.N])`. That worked!